# The handle to window is not found just after showing MessageBox but after 1 second it is found

Tags: c#, dll, messagebox

I show `MessageBox` and close it after 1 second by finding it by `FindWindow` function and then sending `const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;` to this `MessageBox`. The closing is success, but before I close it I try to move it to the upperright corner of the screen, but just after creating `MessageBox` by `MessageBox.Show()` it cannot be found.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
    static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);


    const UInt32 WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;

    static Thread thread;


    static void CloseMessageBox() {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, "Success!");
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {//ALWAYS FALSE DOES NOT FIND THE MESSAGEBOX
            MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, 300, 300, true);
            // PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            Debug.WriteLine("HERE 1");
        }

    }

    static void ShowMessageBox() {
        MessageBox.Show("Data has been loaded!", "Success!");
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, "Success!");
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {//ALWAYS FALSE DOES NOT FIND THE MESSAGEBOX
            Debug.WriteLine("HERE 2");
            MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, 300, 300, true);
        }
    }

    public static void Seed() {
        thread = new Thread(ShowMessageBox);
            new Thread(() => {
                thread.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                CloseMessageBox();
            }).Start();
   }
```

Comment: When `MessageBox.Show()` exits, the window doesn't exist anymore. Your `FindWindow()` inside of `ShowMessageBox()` is after `Show()` has exited. Your `FindWindow()` inside of `CloseMessageBox()` should be able to find it, though (why are you calling `Start()` twice on the same thread, though?).You might consider using [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) or [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx), either one can tell you exactly when the message box window is created and destroyed...

Comment: ... or better, just use [`MessageBoxTimeout()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7914/MessageBoxTimeout-API) instead of sending `WM_CLOSE` manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau One thread creates MessageBox other one closes it after 1 sec so the rest of GUI can proceed even when the MessageBox is still displayed.  After analyzing your post I think that this should work http://wklej.org/id/2536551/ but it doesn't

Comment: there is a timing issue in your code. The closing thread starts the showing thread and then *immediately* calls `FindWindow()` before the showing thread has a chance to call `MessageBox.Show()`. The `Sleep()` gives the showing thread time to show the messagebox. Try adding `Sleep(0)` to the beginning of the closing thread so the OS can task switch to the showing thread.  Or better, have the showing thread start and stop the closing thread, not the other way around. Or better, stop this nonsense and just use `MessageBoxTimeout()` and get rid of your closing thread altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt .NET world `MessageBox.Show` message box can be found or controlled by native API calls. Better try with `MessageBox` API itself. Also ensure that API import and string are both Unicode. I have had problems with `FindWindow` also when searching by caption!

I would suggest to give Spy++ tool a try on how windows are placed, and if they can be found. Z-order, parent/child relationship also matters.